# Chrome error: "Inspected target disconnected. Once it reloads we will attach to it automatically."

Tags: google-chrome, asynchronous, promise

I receive a Chrome (43.0.2357.124) "Aw, snap!" error that renders "Inspected target disconnected. Once it reloads we will attach to it automatically." in the developer console.

Without being too specific to my project and trying to make the question more generally applicable, it appears to occur occur during a Promise that features a ~5 second delay.

This function (can be seen in context on the repo https://github.com/mitTransportAnalyst/CoAXs/blob/master/public/scripts/main/services/analystService.js#L35-L44) performs fine on Firefox 38.0.5. It is receiving a large GeoJSON array - perhaps that could somehow be related to the issue, though I do not know for sure.

At this point, any advice on next steps for how to debug this would be appreciated, even googling this specific issue doesn't come up with any results (5 irrelevant results as of Wed 6:00, June 17: https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&biw=1280&bih=678&q=%22inspected%20target%20disconnected%22%20chrome&oq=%22inspected%20target%20disconnected%22%20chrome&gs_l=serp.3...805885.806603.1.806844.2.2.0.0.0.0.72.122.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..2.0.0.O7y1WqVbj0c&pbx=1&psj=1&ion=1&cad=cbv&sei=LvKBVfarHcyw-AHVioHYBg&rct=j#q=%22Inspected+target+disconnected%22+chrome).

---

Added this as a comment but interested to see if anyone knows why this happened:

Issue ended up being related to the delayed receipt of > 3 MB files (assembled piecemeal). There is some (limited) documentation of this error occurring here code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3968 (the results of which are, unfortunately, inconclusive). Ended up working with the data provider and reducing file size substantially, which resolved the issue. Curiously - if anyone can posit as to why this was occurring - `console.log`ing where `data` was concatenated seemed to avoid the issue. If this didn't occur, the tab would suddenly exceed ~1.3GB and crash.

You can see link to point where I was `console.log`ing here: https://github.com/mitTransportAnalyst/CoAXs/blob/master/public/scripts/analyst.js#L10343

Comment: The error just means what it says: the webpage you inspected crashed. Not in terms of "javascript exception", but in terms of "browser crash" (maybe out-of-memory if that "GeoJSON array" is too large). If you can reproduce this, file a bug with Chrome. Does it also happen without devtools?

Comment: When did this start? I just got version `43.0.2357.124 m` and this started happening on pages where I download some Google OAuth files and makes requests to it. As soon as the dev tools opens up, it crashes.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - it ended up being related to the delayed receipt of > 3 MB files (assembled piecemeal). There is some (limited) documentation of this error occurring here https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3968 (the results of which are, unfortunately, inconclusive). Ended up working with the data provider and reducing file size substantially, which resolved the issue. Curiously - if anyone can posit as to why this was occurring - `console.log`ing where `data` was concatenated seemed to avoid the issue. If this didn't occur, the tab would suddenly exceed ~1.3GB and crash.

Comment: I get the same error, But I don't understand your solution. In my case it occurs when I do SVG draw effect, is it "out of memory" issue? I am using css @keyframes animation for the svg

Comment: @Engineeroholic I think it might be related to Out of Mem issue, but the fact that the file itself was not substantial enough to cause it, and that it only could occur when streaming in the data (only in Chrome) means something else was amiss.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off your extensions. I had a Knockoutjs context debugger plugin and it caused the very same behaviour with the same version of Chrome.

Comment: I've disabled all the extensions, deleted all the history and the AppData\Local\Google\Chrome. The problem persists. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Rollback Chrome or try the canary release?

Answer (score 1):

I just have the same problem. When i check code that have a infinity loop.  That is add the same object again and again it takes high memory. When it full the ram then the page is going to unresponsive. When i check it in Mozilla Firefox the ram full alert is shown in my Antivirus. Chrome can handle it but Mozilla can't take it.  It will loop as it's possible. So don't blame chrome it is handle the exception. Check the codes. If its not your page then leave it.

Finally check the loops....